# Should the reading of an int field be synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the book "Java Concurrency in Practice" the following code is attached:

```
public class Counter {
    private long value = 0;

    public synchronized long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        ++value;
    }
}
```

Here is the value field with type long, as well as synchronized read and increment methods.

Do I understand correctly that the synchronization of the read method is needed only for the long and double types, because they are not atomic? And if the field value is of type int, synchronization of the read method will be unnecessary?

Comment: You can have an AtomicLong but in this case, the `synchronized` keyword is achieving the same result.

Comment: The field type here has no bearing  on whether it needs to be synchronised or not, that question becomes invalid. And you can use synchronisation instead of atomic but you don’t need to. Your questions are invalid.

Comment: The question is, must reading  be synchronized anyway ? I mean, reading this way, you are showing. Be aware that `increment()` is not using `getValue()`, if your doubts is coming from here.

Comment: @PeterMmm yes, question about it

Comment: Even with `int` synchronization needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the `getValue` method.

In Java, the `synchronized` keyword gives you both visibility and atomicity guarantees. As a rule of thumb, you should remember that the compiler developers and CPU vendors are free to do optimizations such as memory reordering or caching variables in registers as **long as the behavior of the optimized program remains unchanged in a single-threaded environment.**

Now let's see what happens when different threads call the `getValue` and `increment` methods, and the `getValue` is no longer synchronized. From the perspective of JVM, any thread that only reads the `value` and never updates it through the `increment` method is effectively always reading the same constant value. So inside the reader thread, JVM might choose to save the variable in a register and never read it from memory again!

As the comments have suggested, the `synchronized` keyword can be removed by changing the type of `value` from an `int` to `AtomicInteger`. But even if you don't want to use an `AtomicInteger`, you can rewrite your class like this:

```
public class Counter {
    private volatile int value = 0;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        ++value;
    }
}
```

The `volatile` keyword will ensure visibility, and the reads no longer require any locking. I suggest checking these references to learn more about Java Memory Model:

https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/index.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html

Comment: Thank you. But if the type is int, can i just delete the synchronization form the read method without volatile?

Comment: No, you can't. The visibility problem would still remain. The writes may never become visible to the threads that never enter the synchronized block.